# How to assert array value but not strict?

Tags: laravel, laravel-testing

How can we assert **some** of the array's property values which contain the expected object values?

My code below is working okay, but it checks all array property values. I want to ask if there's a way we can check only **some** of it.

---

```
$dataToBeTested = [
    'name' => 'Johnny',
    'address' => 'Somewhere',
    'age' => 21,
    'card_no' => 13331577121,
    'rep_no' => 441546661,
    'status' => 'in-progress',
    'created_at' => '2022-07-31T10:05:27.011000Z',
    'updated_at' => '2022-07-31T10:05:27.011000Z',
];

$expectedPropValue = [
    'name' => 'Johnny',
    'address' => 'Somewhere',
    'age' => 21,
];
```

as expected it will return fail, since `expectedPropValue` has some missing properties.

```
$this->assertEquals($dataToBeTested, $expectedPropValue);
```

Goal is something like this,

```
$this->assertSomeOfIt($dataToBeTested, $expectedPropValue); // return true
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for assertArraySubset, Which it's been deprecated with the newer version of PHPUnit. As mentioned here https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/issues/3494. But you can always introduce your approach and use it for your project. Or you can also try this package https://packagist.org/packages/dms/phpunit-arraysubset-asserts. which gives you what you need

```
self::assertArraySubset($expectedSubset, $content, true);
```